# CMD copy doesnt fully copy

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to copy 2 files together in order to append one to the other. I am using the following:

```
copy /Y D:\DB2\db2list.txt+D:\DB2\ugluk_Db2.txt D:\DB2\final_Db2.txt
```

It returns saying 1 file copied but when I see the file it is not even close to the size total that it should be. For instance, db2list.txt is 64MB and ugluk_Db2.txt is 4MB, the combined total should be at least 68MB, but the "successful" copy is 12MB and missing a lot of data (I found specific lines and tried to find it in the final.

Am I doing something wrong with the copy? I tried XCopy as well but to no avail.

Comment: `/B` (binary mode) is required to reliably use `+`.

Comment: Had no idea that was required, thanks it works now!